# mySQL: AND OR functions in WHERE not working with extract datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

You can fiddle with the queries [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68c9bb/6).
These queries aren't returning cities with dates in 2020, 2018 and 2019 consecutively.
Only one city has them all.
You can refer to the table schema below and on the provided link.

```
    select p.city, p.dist
    from t as p
    where extract(year from dist) =  2018 AND 2019 AND 2020;
```

So I tried to group by city and use having.

```
    select p.city, p.dist
    from t as p
   group by p.city
   having extract(year from dist) =  2018 AND 2019 AND 2020;
```

What is wrong in this query?

SCHEMA

| City | Dist |
| --- | --- |
| paris | 01-01-2019 |
| paris | 01-01-2018 |
| paris | 01-01-2020 |
| london | 01-01-2019 |
| glasgow | 01-01-2019 |

Comment: Only Paris should be returned since only Paris has 2020, 2019 and 2018

Comment: see the fiddle link in my answer. It is working with IN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `AND` should be *boolean expressions*.  If they are not, then the expressions are converted to booleans, with `0` as false and any other non-`NULL` values as true.  Hence, your logic is simply:

```
where extract(year from dist) = 2018 AND TRUE AND TRUE
```

so this returns only values from 2018.

You may be trying to write:

```
select p.city, p.dist
from t as p
where extract(year from dist) in (2018, 2019, 2020);
```

This returns rows from any of the three years.

However, it is better to use direct date comparisons:

```
where dist >= '2018-01-01' and dist < '2021-01-01'
```

This is better because it helps the optimizer choose the best execution plan.

The use of `AND` suggests that you want cities present in all three years.  If so, you do want aggregation:

```
select p.city
from t as p
where dist >= '2018-01-01' and dist < '2021-01-01'
group by p.city
having count(distinct year(dist)) = 3;
```

Comment: dist < '2021-01-01' is this the same as dist <= '2020-12-31' ?

Comment: @RealSlimShady . . . The `<` works even if the column has a time component.  I strongly recommend using it, so you don't have to worry about whether or not a date/time component has a time component.

Comment: Alright, and is there any reason why you have used EXTRACT and the YEAR() function ? I had never heard of the YEAR() fn so I always used EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM ...) ?

Comment: @RealSlimShady . . . `EXTRACT()` is fine -- and it is standard SQL.  However, `YEAR()` is convenient.  And i think more databases support it than support `EXTRACT()`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `=  2018 AND 2019 AND 2020;` to `IN (2018,2019,2020);`

[working fiddle  here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68c9bb/19) :

Answer (score 1):

A more MySQL specific option, it reads like "get the city if you can find the year in the list of years":

```
    select p.city
         , p.dist
         , group_concat(distinct year(dist)) years
    from t as p
   group by p.city
   having find_in_set( 2018, years )
      and find_in_set( 2019, years )
      and find_in_set( 2020, years )
```